# calling Java method arguments into array in MatLab

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, function

After creating the java class path for JAR file in MatLab. I am calling the java method that return argument for every 1 sec of type double. How to save this return arguments into the Array ?

```
import com.IPConn;
import com.V2;             % Java Class from JAR file
import java.util.ArrayList;

al = handle(V2(UI, ipcon), 'CallbackProperties'); % creating device Object which is the hardware(micro controller) sends the data
set(al,'callback',@(handles,event) event.getsource);
al.period(1000);           % This gives the event.getsource for every 1 sec
```

Is there any way to store this recurring values of getsource in to the array for example A=[250;500;....] by using Java Array List import or some other functions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from your question, you have a java method which is returning an int. And this java method is getting called multiple times from Matlab and you want to store it's output in an array in Matlab.

Here is how you can do it:

Java code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class StackOverflow {
    public static int getRandomInt() {
        int max = 10;
        int min = 1;
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

Build this into a jar and invoke it in Matlab as follows:

```
javaclasspath('/full/path/to/your.jar')
import StackOverflow
so = StackOverflow;
A = zeros(1,5);
for i=1:5
    A(i) = so.getRandomInt;
end
```

The resultant variable A will have your desired array.